# Can I transfer my friends BO4 updates from his PS4 to my PS4?

Tags: ps4

My old PS4 data got deleted but my friend's didn't. I was wondering if I could move his updates from his system to my PS4.

I have really bad internet that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

The PS4 deletes patch files once they have been used to update the base game files so there is no file on your friend's PS4 that can be manually transferred.

Even if you could get a hold of the patch file from another internet source, there is no official support for manually updating a game via USB on PS4.

What you can try to do is transfer the entire game data from your friends PS4 to your PS4 using an external hard drive. This has it's own problems though,

1. You may run in to licensing issues if your copies are digital, it may want your friend to be logged in in order for you to use the transferred game.
2. You need to have a portable hard drive big enough.
3. You friend will not be able to access their game once it is transferred and will need to re-install or download it to their system.

It is not possible to copy a game data from the system hard drive to the external hard drive using the PS4. You can do this by manually plugging the PS4 hard drive in to a PC to get around item 3.

Comment: It's possible to move (not copy though) any game from internal storage to external, see "How to Move Applications Between External Storage and Your PS4" on https://support.playstation.com/s/article/PS4-External-HDD-Support?language=en_US

Comment: That is what I was trying to say in the answer. I don't think it is good solution to this problem.